# Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS Nvidia driver 530 graphic card not working/detected

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I was using Ubuntu 21.10 (and stuck on that) on a dual boot with windows 10. The graphic card then was working perfectly. So I made a fresh install of Ubuntu and went for the LTS, though I'd remove windows as I wasn't using it anymore. But since the fresh install, the graphic card won't work correctly (or at all).

I have a NVIDIA Geforce GTX 1650.

I installed differents drivers, now I'm back with the 530 and my graphic card isn't detected anymore.
I've run these commands with the results.

```
sudo apt install linux-generic
```

> Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait Construction de l'arbre des
> dépendances... Fait Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
> linux-generic est déjà la version la plus récente (5.15.0.72.70). 0
> mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 26 non mis à
> jour.

-->No new updates to do.

```
dkms status
```

--> Doesn't return anything

```
nvidia-settings
```

> ERROR: A query to find an object was unsuccessful
>
> (nvidia-settings:6465): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 11:40:58.959:
> g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
>
> ** (nvidia-settings:6465): CRITICAL **: 11:40:58.961: ctk_powermode_new: assertion '(ctrl_target != NULL) && (ctrl_target->h
> != NULL)' failed
>
> ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file or the X
> server is
> not accessible. This file should have been installed along with this
> driver at
> /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation. The
> application profiles will continue to work, but values cannot be
> prepopulated or validated, and will not be listed in the help text.
> Please see the README for possible values and descriptions.

```
cat /var/log/gpu-manager.log
```

> log_file: /var/log/gpu-manager.log
> last_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
> new_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
> can't access /opt/amdgpu-pro/bin/amdgpu-pro-px
> Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.19.0-42-generic/kernel
> Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.19.0-42-generic/kernel/nvidia-530-open
> Found nvidia.ko module in /lib/modules/5.19.0-42-generic/kernel/nvidia-530-open/nvidia.ko
> Looking for amdgpu modules in /lib/modules/5.19.0-42-generic/kernel
> Looking for amdgpu modules in /lib/modules/5.19.0-42-generic/updates/dkms
> Is nvidia loaded? yes
> Was nvidia unloaded? no
> Is nvidia blacklisted? no
> Is intel loaded? no
> Is radeon loaded? no
> Is radeon blacklisted? no
> Is amdgpu loaded? no
> Is amdgpu blacklisted? no
> Is amdgpu versioned? no
> Is amdgpu pro stack? no
> Is nouveau loaded? no
> Is nouveau blacklisted? yes
> Is nvidia kernel module available? yes
> Is amdgpu kernel module available? no
> Vendor/Device Id: 10de:1f0a
> BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
> Is boot vga? yes
> Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
> Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
> Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
> Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
> Does it require offloading? no
> last cards number = 1
> Has amd? no
> Has intel? no
> Has nvidia? yes
> How many cards? 1
> Has the system changed? No
> Takes 0ms to wait for nvidia udev rules completed.
> Single card detected
> Nothing to do

I'm a bit lost as to what I can do to make it work.
Right now I have the driver installed, but the card isn't detected by my system. And when I used the X.Org driver the card was detected, but not working.
Can anyone help me find a way to make this work ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I ran same commands and nothing is working. If you haven't tried it (but very likely you have) go to the software and updates and try to update from there I was able to run it and after a few restarts everything seems to be ok.

FYI: it might boot u to Xserver drivers after the first restart so you may have to do another after that.

Answer (score 0):

My solution. Kernel Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS nvidia RTX3070 - FIX install Kernel 5.19.5 (I first installing 325 (all normal working) then, I installing driver 535, installation failed, black screen, force to restart the PC) and 535 working. .

Comment: The black screen is caused by installing the NVIDIA binary Xorg driver (xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-535). Rebooting solves this problem.